# can't stream file to google-cloud when using limit with bodyParser.raw

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage, body-parser

I am using google cloud storage to save images. so far I managed to upload without any problem using pipe and this line:

```
bucket.file(dest).createWriteStream({ resumable: false, metadata: { contentType: contentType } })
```

now, I would like to limit the image size, using body parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ limit: '10mb', type: 'image/*' }));
```

but for some reason, when adding it, I can't save the images on google storage, it creates the file, but with 0 bytes.

any idea why? or how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm also having really crazy problems with this, cannot get a POST body regardless of what I do.